# How to hide part of the datatable under some condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

How to hide part o data table under some condition through LINQ ?

If i have a datatable like this

```
id   name   flag   value   dep   hours

1    aa      0       20     3      22

2    bb      1       35     47     5

3    cc      2       77     23     7

4    aaa     0       13     98     19

5    bbb     1       67     3201   2

6    ccc     2       66     452    4
```

---

Now i want when the `flag = 2` to hide part of the datatable like the following :

```
id   name   flag   value   dep   hours

1    aa      0       20     3      22

2    bb      1       35     47     5

3    cc      2                     7

4    aaa     0       13     98     19

5    bbb     1       67     3201   2

6    ccc     2                     4
```

Comment: A `DataTable` contains _data_, you cannot "hide" it, you just can delete it from the table. Of course you can _hide_ it wherever you display it(f.e in a `DataGridView`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter:hmmm, okay how to remove part of it not the whole row (i mean `cells`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, a `DataTable` contains *data*, you cannot "hide" it, you just can delete it from the table. Of course you can *hide* it wherever you display it(f.e in a `DataGridView`).

You:

> hmmm, okay how to remove part of it not the whole row, i mean cells?

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int flag = row.Field<int>("flag");
    if(flag == 2)
    {
        row.SetField("value", new Nullable<int>());
        row.SetField("dep",   new Nullable<int>());
    }
}
```

Comment: `row.SetField("value", new Nullable<int>());row.SetField("dep", new Nullable<int>());`
Right ?

Comment: how to set string with null value ,i try to set it with `string.Empty` but still has the old value !!

Comment: @just_name: what type is it, `int` or `string`? However, the way i've shown above works with `int`-columns, i have tested it. If it's a string you could assign `DBNull.Value` or (if desired) `String.Empty`, f.e.: `row.SetField("value", DBNull.Value);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operators at the time of retrieving data in your LINQ query as::

```
var data=(from table_name in DataContextName.Table_Name
            select new
            {
                id=table_name.id,
                name=table_name.name,
                flag=table_name.flag,
                value=(table_name.flag==2? "" : table_name.value),
                dep=(table_name.flag==2? "" : table_name.dep),
                hours=table_name.hours
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement it directly on your linq. Please see sample below.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("flag");
            dt.Columns.Add("value");
            dt.Columns.Add("dep");


            dt.Rows.Add("0", "20", "3");
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "35", "47");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "77", "23");


            var myResults = from o in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select new
                            {
                                flag = o.Field<string>("flag"),
                                value = (o.Field<string>("flag") == "1") ? string.Empty : o.Field<string>("value"),
                                dep = (o.Field<string>("flag") == "1") ? string.Empty : o.Field<string>("dep")
                            };
```